# How do I send a div value to a function in angular controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myShoppingList", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.products = ["Milk", "Bread", "Cheese"];
    $scope.addItem = function () {
        $scope.errortext = "";
        if (!$scope.addMe) {return;}
        if ($scope.products.indexOf($scope.addMe) == -1) {
            $scope.products.push($scope.addMe);
        } else {
            $scope.errortext = "The item is already in your shopping list.";
        }
    }
    $scope.removeItem = function (x) {
        $scope.errortext = "";
        $scope.products.splice(x, 1);
    }
});
</script>

<div ng-app="myShoppingList" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in products">{{x}}<span ng-click="removeItem($index)">×</span></li>
  </ul>
  <input ng-model="addMe">
  <button ng-click="addItem()">Add</button>
  <p>{{errortext}}</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**The line `<input ng-model="addMe">` takes the input values and adds to the list**
What if I want to define a `<div>` instead of `<input>` to send the value to my controller instead of `<input>` ? I have been trying this for long now and can not get a value enclosed between `<div>` and `</div>` sent over to the controller.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more clear on the question? What do you want to send to the controller?

Comment: Or in more general terms;  what are you trying to do?

Comment: The thing is I have the following div:
 <div ng-repeat="x in products" style="margin-bottom: 25px;" ng-model="x.product">
                     
                     <div class="col-lg-1">{{ $index + 1 }}</div>
                     <div class="col-lg-4">{{ x.product }}</div>
                     <div class="col-lg-4">${{ x.price }}</div>
                     <div class=" col-lg-3 btn btn-primary" ng-click="addToCart()">Add to cart</div>

                   </div>

The thing I want is when I click on add to cart button I should see it on the cart

Comment: is not it working?

Comment: The question is why do you want to send a div value? A div doesn't have a `value` and therefore doesn't have a `ngModel` directive, it only has `innerHTML`. You would have to do some DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your `x` as parameter on `addToCart` to add it to cart in the controller.

See demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vincentluth/05b9gdgg/).